# Adjective to describe an argument that changed my mind or makes good sense?

Tags: single-word-requests

I recently read an opinion piece that I found to be totally convincing - it expressed things that I'd felt myself but had never previously been able to put into words - it hit the nail on the head.

When I was sending someone else a link to the article, I realised I couldn't think of a single adjective that expressed how I wanted to describe it. "You should read this **_** article from (author)".

Does anyone have any ideas? I've come up with "convincing" and "incisive" but I don't think they quite express what I'm looking for. A thesaurus gave me "trenchant" which I think is a bit too obscure.

Comment: what about STFU? Example,  "I tried to argue we shouldn't get married but her hair made me STFU."

Comment: "Cogent" to me implies an argument that is well thought out and technically convincing.

Comment: Can I get a link to that article please? :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Compelling** comes to mind.

[merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compelling) tells us:

> very interesting : able to capture and hold your attention
>   **capable of causing someone to believe or agree**
>   strong and forceful : causing you to feel that you must do something
>   [...]
>   He made a **compelling argument**.

Another option might be **persuasive**, as Gary's Student mentions in his comment. As [merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persuasive) defines it:

> able to cause people to do or believe something
>   able to persuade people

Comment: Also a *persuasive* argument.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent that's an alternative indeed. Thanks, I added it :)

Comment: Yes, I think **persuasive** is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: compelling .. nice.

Comment: "Compelling" is the first word that sprung to my mind.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not normally keen on "grading" alternative ways of expressing something, because people don't always agree over which words are "stronger" or "weaker". But in this particular case I think almost everyone would agree that given...

> *Tom presented a convincing argument*
>    *Dick presented a compelling argument*
>    *Harry presented a **killer argument***

...we take it for granted that Harry would win hands if it came to a vote. In which context it's worth noting that we can quite naturally replace ***a*** with ***the*** killer argument (there's usually only ***one*** killer argument trumping all others), but it would be a bit odd to do that with the alternatives.

Comment: Good one, also *knock-down* argument maybe

Comment: @Joe: I do *know* that version, but it's not so familiar to me. I just compared US/UK usage in Google Books, and was somewhat surprised to find that whereas it's been steadily declining in the US since its heyday in the late 1800s, it's actually become *more* prevalent in the British corpus over recent decades. But not everything suggested by Google Books is necessarily a true reflection of reality.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: That certainly wasn't my intention. I *wanted* to highlight my actual proposed *"**adjective** to describe an argument"* by making it a link to a [***killer argument dictionary***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=killer+argument+dictionary&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=killer+argument+dictionary&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.1985860j0j0&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) definition, but I couldn't find one. Which is a bit odd, since it's a well-known idiom (with a lot of links to *translations* into other languages, in my Google search there).

Comment: I'm just saying what it "looks" like at a glance. It could be that users perceive your post containing three answers, all three expressions are in bold. I'm just saying!

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I obviously haven't presented the killer argument for why my answer should have more votes! :) I could try removing the highlights for the other words, to see if that gets me any more votes, but I don't think it'll ever overtake *compelling*. I suppose it depends on whether you interpret OP's question as asking for the most ***common*** adjective for a "strong" case/argument, or asking for the adjective that *unambiguously identifies the **strongest** one*.

Answer (score 4):

Try the adjective *cogent* if you want to say the argument is logical, well-organized, and persuasive.    [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cogent#Adjective) shows the following senses:

> 1. Reasonable and convincing; based on evidence.
> 2. Appealing to the intellect or powers of reasoning.
> 3. Forcefully persuasive.

If the article helps in choosing one point of view from among several, or if it expresses an argument nearly irrefutably, consider *[decisive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decisive#Adjective)*, with its sense “Having the power or quality of deciding a question or controversy; putting an end to contest or controversy; final; conclusive”.

An article that presents its argument neatly and compactly may be called *pithy*.  From [en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pithy), it means “Concise and meaningful”.

Also consider *[enlightening](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enlightening)*, present participle of verb *[enlighten](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enlighten#English)*, which is “To make clear to the intellect or conscience; to shed the light of truth and knowledge upon; to furnish with increase of knowledge; to instruct; as, to enlighten the mind or understanding”.

Answer (score 3):

[Influential](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Influential) may also convey the idea:

> - having the power to cause changes : having influence
> - having or exercising influence or power; "an influential newspaper"; "an influential speech"
>
>   - His theories have become more influential in recent years.
>   - My parents have been the most influential people in my life.

Source: www.thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 2):

**Telling**

as in, "It was a telling argument."

telling adjective

: producing a strong or important effect

: giving information about someone or something without intending to

[Source](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.merriam-webster.com%2Fdictionary%2Ftelling&ei=GLMhVISiGMXw8AHE3oDACQ&usg=AFQjCNHhu7lUZduMqKNaWK-Yc4UV9zscDA&sig2=54AF0X_T-D4eE-S7laUi3A)

I had to add a second one, because it was bothering me that nobody had...

**Cogent**

1:  having power to compel or constrain

2a :  appealing forcibly to the mind or reason :  convincing

[source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cogent)

Comment: sweet -- you're the SWR Elegance award for today.  A telling argument.

Comment: Please cite your source, before the "attribution police" comes along and deletes your post. (no kidding!) Now, was that a *telling argument* or a *persuasive one*?

Comment: Interestingly it's etymology, is from the meaning "to count or measure" as In "the clock tells time"...

Answer (score 1):

Powerful.

> It was a **powerful** article that changed my mind.

In your case, I would also suggest **elucidatory**, as you are not simply describing a compelling argument, but one that *clarified* some pre-conceived ideas and *elucidated* them in a way you were unable to.